# Inserting the Date from JSpinner Component into Oracle DB in the correct format

Tags: oracle, date, netbeans, jspinner

So I've been trying to insert the date from a JSpinner component into an Oracle DB.
The date format of a sample entry in the Oracle table is like "2018-01-01 09:30:00.0" (image for reference):

[image]

I want to save the value obtained from the JSpinner in the same format as otherwise, I'm getting a Unparseable date exception.

For reference this is the date I enter in the spinner : 
[image: Date and Time entered into Jspinner]

and this is the error that shows up : 
[image]

This is the code I'm using to try and insert it into the Oracle DB:

```
  TimeReserved = jSpinner1.getValue().toString();
  String Query = "Insert into RoomTable Values( ?, ?, ?)";
  PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(Query);
  //setting Date
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh-mm-ss a" );
        Date fd = formatter.parse(TimeReserved);
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(fd.getTime());
        stmt.setDate(2, sqlDate);
```

Additionally, I've set the editor property up like this : 
[image]

Thank you guys for your help in advance :)

Comment: "*The date format of a sample entry in the Oracle table is*" - no it is not. `DATE` columns do **not** have any format.

Comment: Oh I thought the format is yyyy-mm-dd hh-mi-ss in that column since it is saved as such. I figured the problem is because the jspinner is saving the date with Day and Timezone (according to the parse exception)  and such instead of just in the  yyyy-mm-dd hh-mi-ss format

Comment: Any "format" you see is applied by the SQL client _displaying_ that value.

Comment: `hh-mm-ss` should probably be `hh-mi-ss` (minute not month number).

Comment: I've realized one of the errors is that I had put ss instead of dd in the date format section. However, i'm still getting the ParseException.

Comment: @William Robertson the simple date formatter doesn't allow you to set mi I think. It throws the illegal character exception. I don't know how to extract only the yyyy-MM-dd hh-mm-dd values from the jSpinner to save in the database

Comment: Oh, in that case jSpinner probably uses a different notation to Oracle, and `MM` is month and `mm` is minute. Forget what I said :)